# newton raphson question

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Find a cut point of the $y = x^3-4x-5$ and $y = e^x-4x-5$ curves by selecting the starting point $x_0 = 3$, using the Newton Raphson method with an error of $10^{-3}$

I can't solve the question. Can you help me?

Comment: I´ve made an edit. Please check if my interpretation was right and give a reply.

Comment: correct, thank you for the correction

Comment: Did you notice the equation you need to solve ?

Comment: yes I continued that way but i could not find the value less than 10 ^ -3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the cut point we set both function equal.

$x^3-4x-5= e^x-4x-5$

Next we subtract $e^x-4x-5$ on both side of the equation.

$$x^3-4x-5- e^x+4x+5=0\Rightarrow g(x)=x^3-e^x=0$$

So we want to evaluate the root of $g(x)$. The crucial formula of the Newton-Raphson method is

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)}$$

Firstly we calculate the derivative $g'(x)=3x^2-e^x$. We have the initial value $x_0=3$. So you can go on and calculate $x_1$.

$$x_1=3-\frac{g(3)}{g'(3)}=3-\frac{3^3-e^3}{3\cdot 3^2-e^3}=2$$

The (absolute) error is $|x_1-x_0|=|2-3|=1$. This is greater than $10^{-3}$. So you have to go on.

$$x_2=2-\frac{g(2)}{g'(2)}=\ldots$$

```
            g(x)    x_(n)-x_(n-1) 
x1  2       0.61094 1
x2  1.8675  0.04092 0.13250
x3  1.8572  0.00025 0.01025
x4  1.8572  0.00000 0.00006
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, I was solving the question in this way, but I could not find a value less than 10 ^ -3.

Comment: I can post some value of $x_i$. But it takes some minutes.

Comment: I'm waiting for you, thank you very much for your help, by the way.

Comment: @MehmetKömürcüoğlu You´re welcome.I´ve made an edit. I hope you can find the mistake.

Comment: thank you for your help, i hope you find the error

Comment: @MehmetKömürcüoğlu Have you succeeded?

Comment: Yes, I did it, thanks to you. Thank you again.

Comment: @MehmetKömürcüoğlu You´re welcome. I would appreciate if you marked the question as accepted $\large{\left(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)} $.